# Does a more powerful CPU read files faster (ex: a CSV?)

Tags: python, cpu

What aspects do (and do not) effect the speed at which a computer can read files? Say for example, Python reading a CSV.

I am guessing cores do not matter. I am guessing even threads don't matter. But perhaps the ghz matter?

Comment: Unless you're reading from a slow disk (and the disk cache is cold), then yes, parsing a CSV will typically be CPU-bound.  And usually truly CPU, not memory bandwidth, especially in a language like Python, especially slow implementations like the standard CPython.  So yes, single-threaded / per-thread performance would be what matters.   clock speed times average IPC (instructions per cycle).  CSV-parsing is hard to parallelize unless you have an index to know the byte offset for the start of a line some ways into a file, and Python makes it hard to do threading anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what's limiting the read operation.
Most things are either I/O bound or CPU bound.

Basically: If the CPU is giving instructions to fetch data and move it around, but the data has to come from the network or a (slow) disk, a faster CPU won't help as the program (and the CPU) spends most of its time waiting for data to arrive.

If, on the other hand, the program itself gives the CPU so much work that a slow CPU can't keep up, then a faster CPU does speed things up.

Comment: Interesting. Can you speak more to what tasks might be demanding for the CPU when reading?

Comment: "Reading" is pretty much always I/O-bound unless it's reading from a cache inside the CPU or from RAM (even then, probably).
Pure calculations, however, are likely CPU-bound. Say a program reads data (during which it is likely going to be I/O-bound) and then runs tons of multiplications, divisions, etc. on that data. That is going to be CPU-bound at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe?

We are missing too much information to reach a conclusion. For a large file, you will likely be constrained by the slowest step in the parsing process. That could be reading from the disk, accessing RAM, parsing the raw data on the CPU or a large number of other things. The number of cores might matter. Without knowing how the CSV parser is implemented, we can't be sure though. Maybe it breaks the CSV into chunks so it can be parsed by multiple cores.

The bottom line is if you want a definite answer you need to profile the application you have questions about. We can make as many guesses as we want, but at the end of the day profiling the program is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Most CSV formats aren't self-synchronizing; if you seek to half way through the file in bytes, you won't know if a comma or newline you see is inside quotes or not.  Or if a quote you see is a start or end quote.  So you couldn't reliably find the start of a new line.  (Also you wouldn't know the line number, so you wouldn't know what array index to start parsing into.)  Or maybe most CSV formats don't allow newlines even inside quotes, in which case it is easy to find the start of a line even without an index.